# Is it possible to base GroupTemplate (.NET) on anything but a fixed record count?

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I'd like to use ListView to display grouped data from my db. Because of the way the query is structured, each logical group might have 1 **or** 2 records associated with it. Is there anyway to use GroupTemplate, while overridding the GroupItemCount behavior? Ideally, I'd like it to behave the way SQL does- assign a column ID, and let it watch for a change in value.

Answer (score 2):

[Ok here it is, nicely documented](https://web.archive.org/web/20210301194237/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/091708-1.aspx)

It would be nice to build this kind of functionality directly into the control so you can simply specify this "watch" field using markup.

Again, this is the reason why I switched to the ListView, to try to avoid lengthy workarounds like this where you have to manually inject your own HTML. I bet they will eventually add this feature in and then claim how super amazing .Net 4.0 is.

All the time, more and more, I find more reasons to steer clear of inflexible .Net and use one of the more "direct" HTML manipulation platforms (PHP + CodeIgnitor). If you are absolutely fluent with CSS and HTML and know them backwards, you will find .Net uber frustrating every single time, because you just "can't quite get in there" and do what you need to do quickly without searching for workarounds all the time.

Summary: ASP.Net still isn't there yet.